# set IPython Notebook inline plots background not transparent

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

In IPython Notebook 3, when I use the `Inline` matplotlib backend, the png figures in the browser have a transparent background.

How do I set it to white instead?

Minimal example:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2])
```

Right click and save the image, the image has a transparent background, I would like it to be white instead.

**Update**
Tried to set `figure.facecolor` in `matplotlibrc` but it still displays a transparent png:

```
import matplotlib
print("facecolor before:")
print(matplotlib.rcParams["figure.facecolor"])
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2])
print("facecolor after:")
print(matplotlib.rcParams["figure.facecolor"])
```

This code gives as output:

```
facecolor before:
1.0
facecolor after:
(1, 1, 1, 0)
```

Comment: you should use `%matplotlib notebook` instead

Comment: thanks @tcaswell, didn't know about that! however I really would prefer to use the `inline` backend. It looks more lightweight.

Comment: Yes, but it isn't interactive (which is at least half of the power of mpl).

Comment: and the transparent background in hard-coded in to IPython Added in https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/6064 New issue report https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/7964

Comment: thanks @tcaswell for finding this

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Assuming the area that was transparent is everything surrounding the ax (subplot) you can try this:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(facecolor='w')
ax.plot([1,2])
```

If you want to have white background in figures permanently you need to modify you `matplotlibrc` file (located in your home folder under `.matplotlib\`) changing these parameters:

```
figure.facecolor = 1
```

But you can always save you figure automatically with any background you want (independent from what it was when the figure was created) by passing `facecolor`:

```
fig.savefig('filename.png', facecolor='w', transparent=False)
```

Comment: thanks, with `subplots` works correctly. However it does not using `matplotlibrc`. See update in the question.

Comment: Good to hear that at least one approach is solving the problem. You also can use a shortcut for `facecolor` when creating figure by passing `fc='w'`. Still curious why would you prefer right mouse click to `fig.savefig()`...

Comment: the notebook runs on another machine, so `savefig` is not convenient.

Comment: You can also do this in-code using the matplotlib.rcParams dictionary.  Curiously, though, with that `rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = 1` did *not* work.  It had to be `rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = 'w'`

Comment: `plt.rc('figure', facecolor='w')` worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Another option, instead of setting facecolor, is to use the `seaborn` package.

Just run:

```
import seaborn as sns
```

it automatically sets the plot background and also gives better default colors for matplotlib.

Comment: This was the case up to version 0.7 of seaborn, but is not the case any more. Currently you would need to add `sns.set()` to achieve the same effect.